# slice arrays to create cards using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create cards using below example link:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_portfolio&stacked=h

I am using ajax to push cards data in a global array.

```
htmlCards = [];

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: 'xxx.com',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            htmlCards.push("<div class='col-sm-3'><img class='movie-selection' src="+eval(data[i].title.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(':', '').toLowerCase())+" class='img-responsive' style='width:100%'><p class='movie-selection' >"+data[i].title+"</p></div>");
        }
    }
});
```

Now all cards are now pushed to my global array. I am using bootstrap to list all the cards. However i want to give a break of row in each 3 cards listing. Something like below:

```
<div id="listing-main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that using ajax?

***HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!***

Comment: How will you create the dom? by looping over `htmlCards`

Comment: @brk yes...............

Comment: [Don't need to scream for help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) with bold text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something you are looking for

```
var htmlCards = [
  '<img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">',
  '<img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">',
  '<img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">',
  '<img src="https://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">'
]
    for (var i = 0; i < htmlCards.length; i++) {
       var appendDiv = $(htmlCards[i]);
       if (i % 3 === 0) {
         appendDiv = $('<div class="row row' + (i /3) + '">').append(appendDiv);
         $('#listing-main').append(appendDiv);
       } else {
         console.log(Math.floor(i/3));
         $('#listing-main').find('.row' + Math.floor(i/3)).append(appendDiv);
       }

    }
```

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/BrExbZ)